# Stirling number of the first kind equality

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

The question I am looking at asks to use a combinatorial argument to show that

$$ \begin{bmatrix} n \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \frac{n!}{2} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m(n-m)}$$

I tried to use the recurrence relation for Stirling numbers of the first kind but couldn't find a way to make this work, help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Once you recognize that the RHS is $(n-1)! H_{n-1}$, this is pretty obvious from the definition of Stirling numbers of the first kind as coefficients of $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)$, but I do not know if this counts as a *combinatorial proof*. Please add some extra context and your attempts.